# C++ : for; vs for{}

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have seen several times for loop without instructions and they always use ;
but is there a reason why no one use {} ?

Examples :

`for(int i=0; i<5; i++);`

`for(int i=0; i<5; i++){}`

Comment: No. Same thing.  Pretty rare to see either though.

Comment: The difference is stylistic.   A `for` loop requires a single statement after the `)`.   `;` is a single empty statement so does nothing.    `{}` is a single empty block statement, so does nothing.   I've seen both forms.    `{}` is sometimes used as a placeholder when the intent is to add a series of statements within it.

Comment: *why no one use {} ?* -- So you took a survey of all the thousands of C++ programmers around the world, and no one uses `{}`?  I have a few of them in my codebase right now, so I guess you didn't ask me.

Comment: both of them compiles to the same assembly code, and they'll become a simple assignment in optimizing compilers, no loops involved, so don't use them

Comment: I use both, and also `{ ; }` as well, but I always put the controlled-statement on the next line, not the same line, and in the case of `{ ; }` I put it over three lines.

Comment: *"is there a reason why no one use {} ?"* -- this appears to be a [faulty generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization). A better way to phrase this would be *"is there a reason why none of these people used {}"*. It is valid to conclude that none of the samples you looked at used `{}`, but it is not valid to conclude that no one ever uses `{}`. For example, the [Google style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Loops_and_Switch_Statements) encourages `{}` over `;` for empty loop bodies, invalidating your generalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no technical reason, it's mostly a matter of style. Both alternatives are logically identical.

It is true that with some fair frequency we get questions on Stackoverflow along the order of: why doesn't the following loop work correctly:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++);
{
   // Do something
}
```

So, one could argue that a trailing semicolon is easily to overlook, and can be error prone.

But there is no technical difference, otherwise.

Comment: Can't recall offhand if it was on SO, but I've also seen questions due to something like `for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i); simple_statement();` only executing `simple_statement()` once.